# C program to listen to VLC request

Tags: sockets, vlc

Can i write a socket program in c to accept request from vlc player. Assume that i have a vlc player requesting video content from a address say 192.168.1.2 to port 5000. The server program is outputting the video to 5000 of the same ip address.

Comment: VLC can be its own streaming server. What are you trying to accomplish? http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo

Comment: i have to do some processing before streaming to other clients. i cannot store the content on to the disk. I retrieve content from a multicast address do some processing then have to deliver it the client. so basically i act as a router

Answer (score 0):

if you "accept" on a server socket it blocks until a new connection comes in.